# How do vCores work in Virtuozzo Virtualization?

Tags: performance, virtuozzo

We are evaluating vServers based on Virtuozzo.

The marketing says

- 2 dedicated Cores
- 6 virtual Cores

`/proc/cpuinfo` lists two cores. The support told us, that the virtual cores will be used when the computing power is needed, but that is not visible.

What does that mean? How do this vCores function? How can I verify that the performance is boosted?

I made performance tests using

`phoronix-test-suite benchmark pts/hmmer-1.1.0`

and the performance looks more like a two core system.

Comment: What hardware is this running on?

Comment: Also, benchmarks are typically useless. The only truly useful benchmark is to run your intended workload and see how it performs.

Comment: In my professional opinion, some marketing person has given you a large pile of BS. (And I personally would avoid Virtuozzo for anything important...)